is there way to make PagedList insertSeparators analogue?
I have screen that uses Flow<PagedList>, i know that there is PagingData but in my scenario i have to use PagedList. My view is subscribed to this flow and collects it's value to RecyclerView, i want to have separators inside this recycler, how can i implement something like insertSeparators but with PagedList? or may be there is method like this?
Each separator will be calculated based on fields inside Entity and inserted before such entity
I tried to map values with flatMapConcat and emit multiple values inside flow but i had to somehow wrap entities inside PagedList but i dont know how to do it properly
